# Error in transation and ExecuteNonQuery in C#

Tags: c#, sql, transactions

I have the following error:

> ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

This error appears in function executaComando

**My function Save:**

```
public void save(string[] arr)//, int lista)
{
    SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConexao"].ToString());
    conexao.Open();
    SqlTransaction trx = conexao.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        //Truncate cliente_recurso
        BUProjetosDAL dal = new BUProjetosDAL();
        dal.excluirClientesRecurso(conexao);

        dtsRecursoClienteTableAdapters.RECURSO_CLIENTETabelaTableAdapter tabela = new dtsRecursoClienteTableAdapters.RECURSO_CLIENTETabelaTableAdapter();

        for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) { // <- here
            tabela.Insert(arr);
        }

        trx.Commit();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        try
        {
            trx.Rollback();
        }
        catch (Exception exRollback)
        {
            Response.Write(exRollback.Message);
        }  
    }
}
```

**Function excluirClientesRecurso**

```
public void excluirClientesRecurso(SqlConnection conexao)
{
    executaComando("TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.RECURSO_CLIENTE", conexao);
}
```

**Function executaComando (----The error appears here----)**

```
public void executaComando(string query, SqlConnection conexao)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.Connection = conexao;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexao.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, you might want to look at the lack of `using` statements (which could cause connection exhaustion) and the lack of parameterization in your `executaComando` (which suggests that code from other areas may use concatenation of inputs, which would be very bad - risking sql injection among other things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. So pass the transaction in. This is basically your way of convincing it "I know that there is a transaction here". So:

```
dal.excluirClientesRecurso(conexao, trx);
// ...
public void excluirClientesRecurso(SqlConnection conexao,
     SqlTransaction transaction = null)
{
    executaComando("TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.RECURSO_CLIENTE",
        conexao, transaction);
}

public void executaComando(string query, SqlConnection conexao,
     SqlTransaction trasaction = null)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.Trasnaction = transaction;
        // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is exactly as the error says. You opened a transaction but you didn't assign it to the command.

One simple solution would be to simply pass it down to `executaComando`:

```
public void excluirClientesRecurso(SqlConnection conexao,
                                   SqlTransaction transaction)
{
    executaComando("TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.RECURSO_CLIENTE", conexao);
}

public void executaComando(string query, SqlConnection conexao,
                           SqlTransaction transaction)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    cmd.Connection = conexao;
    cmd.Transaction = transaction
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conexao.Close();
}

// Usage
dal.excluirClientesRecurso(conexao, trx);
```

Please note that I removed the try-catch in `executaComando` because it didn't do anything good. In fact, it did bad things: It messed up the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try This code

```
    public bool updateusertable(string UserName,string Password,string Datetime)
            {
                bool bResult = false;
               SqlTransaction tx;
                try
                {
                    tx=Sqlconnect.Begintransaction;
                    SqlCommand Ocmd = new SqlCommand();
                   Sqlconnect= Cconnect.OpenSqlConnection();
                    Ocmd.Connection = Sqlconnect;
                    Ocmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    Ocmd.CommandText = "SP_User_login_Update";
                    Ocmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = UserName;
                    Ocmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Password;
                    Ocmd.Parameters.Add("@lastlogin", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Datetime;
                    int i = Ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (i <= 1)
                    {
                        bResult = true;
                    }else
                    {
                        tx.Rollback();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string msg = ex.Message.ToString();
                    tx.Rollback();
                }
                finally
                {
                    tx.Commit();
                }
                return bResult;
            }
```